# iOS Tesseract couldn't load any languages

Tags: ocr

Tessaract returning below error message

```
Error opening data file /var/mobile/Applications/56987B01-F4A8-480D-B209-3842452035E4/Documents/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
```

Can any one help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it with the following:

set TESSDATA_PREFIX=/Tesseract

Comment: After including path (TESSDATA_PREFIX=C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\) also i am getting same error. I am using tesseract 4.0 software and i tried tesseract 3.x also. Still issue not solved.